# Forcefully loading ONLY Nvidia graphics on boot, and not Intel Integrated?

Tags: 13.04, graphics

Well, I have checked what graphics I am currently using and it is the Intel Integrated graphics driver.  I have installed Bumblebee successfully for my Nvidia GT555M but I need to load it to play my games, however I can't switch because I have no idea how.  I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to find a definite answer.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, on a laptop.  Everything is working fine as-is, I just need to be able to use my dedicated graphics, I don't mind if my Integrated graphics is completely disabled when I boot up.

Please help :).

Comment: Do you have your vga/hdmi pluged in to your nvidia card ? You can only use the gpu your cabel is connected to and you can find nvidia drivers in software and updates app under the additional drivers tab

Comment: or use `optirun application_name`

Comment: Yeah everythings plugged in and when I go to additional drivers it gives me the list of those Nouvier drivers or whatever, the open source ones, but I can't install it since last time I did it disabled unity and I had to reinstall.  But yes, I'm on a laptop and it does work, since I use it on windows.  Web-E I ran that but is there anything I need after it to make it work?  I'm new to Linux

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer so I'll put it up here for everyone to see. Problem was I didn't finish after I installed Bumblebee, I forgot the terminal commands.

Usage

The command line programm optirun shipped with Bumblebee is your best friend for running applications on your Optimus NVIDIA card.

Test Bumblebee if it works with your Optimus system:

```
$ optirun glxgears -info
```

If it succeeds and the terminal you are running from mentions something about your NVIDIA - Optimus with Bumblebee is working!

General usage:

```
$ optirun [options] application [application-parameters]
```

Some Examples:

Start Windows applications with Optimus:

```
$ optirun wine windows application.exe
```

Use NVIDIA Settings with Optimus:

```
$ optirun -b none nvidia-settings -c :8
```

For a list of options for optirun view its manual page.

A new program is soon becoming the default choice because of better performance, namely primus. Currently you need to run this program separately (it does not accept options unlike optirun), but in the future it will be started by optirun. Usage:

```
$ primusrun glxgears
```

FULL DOCUMENTATION 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#Installing_Bumblebee_with_Intel.2FNVIDIA